# Jmeter regex false

Tags: java, php, regex, magento, jmeter

I have a problem with jmeter regular expressions extractor.
I'm using magento jmeter stress test. `https://github.com/magento/magento-performance-toolkit/tree/master/1.14`

Problem is in next part. When i put category url and key in settings, jmeter gives me next errors:

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Response was null
```

This is regular expression extractor:

```
<a href="http://${host}${base_path}(index.php/)?([a-z0-9-]+)${url_suffix}" class="level
```

This if from responce assertion:

```
^[a-z0-9-]+$
```

Example of url:
http://web.stresstest.com/index.php/my-class.html

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is due to a Null response , meaning you didn't get a checkable response.

Could you show the Sampler details and in View Results Tree the request and response ?